# How to access camera in QML QVideoFilterRunnable?

Tags: qt, qml

Following the blog at https://blog.qt.io/blog/2015/03/20/introducing-video-filters-in-qt-multimedia,  I managed to get my C++ filter to work with QML-defined camera. The problem I am running into is that the image that my filter receives does not account for my screen orientation. Qt documentation http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cameraoverview.html shows how to rotate the image based on camera and screen orientations. What is not clear is how to obtain the camera instance from the filter. Here is a relevant snippet from my QML file:

```
Camera {
    id: camera
    captureMode: Camera.CaptureStillImage
    ...
}

MyFilter {
    id: filter
}

VideoOutput {
    id: viewfinder
    source: camera
    filters: [ filter ]
    ...
}
```

How can I access QCamera instance from my QVideoFilterRunnable instance? Regards.

Comment: You can’t access the camera object directly, because the runnable is called in another thread than the QCamera, and QCamera isn’t threadsafe. You’d need to pass the required information to your Filter (as properties) and have the runnable get them from the filter. (and make sure the accesses are threadsafe.

Answer (score 0):

Answer your specific question about rotation, the best answer I have is pass the orientation from the VideoOutput component to your custom component, i.e.

```
Camera {
    id: camera
    captureMode: Camera.CaptureStillImage
    ...
}

MyFilter {
    id: filter
    orientation: videofinder.orientation
}

VideoOutput {
    id: viewfinder
    source: camera
    autoOrientation: true
    filters: [ filter ]
    ...
}
```

That way, your custom filter will know how the end user sees your image. Another gotcha is on some devices the image is flipped as well:

```
#ifdef Q_OS_ANDROID
bool flip = true;
#else
bool flip = surfaceFormat.scanLineDirection() == QVideoSurfaceFormat::BottomToTop;
#endif
```